# "Sguardo d'intesa": come posso dire lo stesso in un altro modo?

Tags: meaning, synonym

Sto leggendo il libro di Gianrico Carofiglio *Né qui né altrove*.  Vorrei che qualcuno mi spiegasse bene il significato dell'espressione "sguardo d'intesa" in riferimento a un brano del libro e mi dicesse come esprimere lo stesso in un altro modo. Conosco quest'espressione, ma non riesco a capirla in questo contesto.

Ecco il brano:

> "Avevamo un vecchio amico tornato a Bari dopo tanti anni e volevamo fare bella figura, disse Giampiero. **Sguardo d'intesa,** volete che ci pensi io? Grazie, ma mi raccomando, questo signore - Giampiero mise una mano sulla spalla di Paolo - deve tornarsene a Chicago sapendo quello che si è perso andando a fare l'americano. Faremo del nostro meglio: **altro sguardo d'intesa**. Faccio io anche per il vino? Fai tu, come al solito."

Comment: Non so in che lingua vuoi che te la si traduca, ma in ogni caso non è questo il sito adatto, in cui si parla appunto solo di italiano e non di altre lingue. Se vuoi, qualcuno potrà spiegarti il senso dell'espressione e poi troverai il modo di renderla in un'altra lingua.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @DaG. Se hai bisogno d'aiuto per capire meglio il senso di quest'espressione nel contesto di questo brano dovresti riformulare la domanda.

Comment: Pensa che, così com'è, la domanda è fuori tema e dovrà essere chiusa. Dovresti fare lo sforzo di riformularla senza fare nessun riferimento a una traduzione nel senso spiegato da @DaG.

Comment: Qualcuno potrebbe spiegarti bene il significato dell'espressione (in inglese se lo preferisci) e poi potresti fare la domanda sulla traduzione in ELU, ma qui dovresti formulare la domanda senza chiedere una traduzione.

Comment: “Look of understanding”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il brano descrive una conversazione tra due personaggi. L'autore non utilizza però la punteggiatura tradizionale per i dialoghi e questo può difficoltare la comprensione. Quando Carofiglio fa uso dell'espressione "sguardo d'intesa" vuol dire che i personaggi si capiscono con un semplice sguardo tra loro. Come ha detto @egreg, in inglese potresti dire "a look of understanding" oppure "a  knowing look" ("both characters are exchanging a look of understanding, they are giving each other a knowing look").

Un sinonimo in italiano potrebbe essere ["occhiata d'intesa"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/occhiata1/).